# Preventing selecting the same data over and over again from a php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, cron

My code below should select data from db and then use the variables to send an SMS. I'm using a cron job to execute the script. The problem is that when cron runs, it also picks the already processed data. Someone please guide me on how to prevent selecting already worked on data....

```
    //should select the fresh or new data after the first run
    $sql = "SELECT name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";


    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data


            $name = $resultarr['name'];
            $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
            $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
            $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

             //message template
            $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

        $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
        $message_sent = $message;

            $serviceArguments = array(
                            "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
                            "message" => $message_sent
            );

            $client = new SoapClient("http://32.138.160.130:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL");
```

Comment: Add a column to your table that says whether an SMS has been sent, and add a `WHERE thisNewColumn = false` or similar.

Comment: Hello there. How do I do this? I have a status column in my table, how do I? Kindly... @JonStirling

Answer (score 0):

Add new column for status of sms. Like sms_sent and default value of this column is 0 and when sms is successfully send then change the sms_sent value 0 to 1.
ANd then sql query is:
$sql = "SELECT name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer WHERE  sms_sent= 0";

---

```
    //should select the fresh or new data after the first run
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";


    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data


            $name = $resultarr['name'];
            $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
            $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
            $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

             //message template
            $message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

        $mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
        $message_sent = $message;

            $serviceArguments = array(
                            "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
                            "message" => $message_sent
            );

            $client = new SoapClient("http://32.138.160.130:8080/smsengine/smsws?WSDL"); 
$sq = "UPDATE customer SET notification = 1 WHERE id = $resultarr['id']";
```

Comment: Thanks. Say I have a 'notification' set at '0' column on my table I should have...`$sql = "SELECT name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer WHERE notification = 0";`  then after sending the sms I should have `$sq = "UPDATE customer SET notification = 1 WHERE notification = 0";` Right? So after some other data is inserted will the notification set revert back to 0 so that I can select? Kindly.. @Kuldeep

Comment: @Bob Myles 
not like that 
"$sq = "UPDATE customer SET notification = 1 WHERE notification = 0";"
Update table after every sms send and update with the help of unique id(Primary key) of that table.

Comment: Okay, like my case, the primary key is "id" ....am not getting you well, kindly elaborate

Comment: Fetch id with the data using below sql query
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";
Update table using below sql query on the specific "id"
$sq = "UPDATE customer SET notification = 1 WHERE id = $resultarr['id']";