# PHP MYSQL select statement with cron job service. Pick new records only

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I need to select records from a database without ever repeating them again. I am using cron. I need the cron service to select only new records after the first run. Kindly, would any one lead me through? Thank you.

```
//should select the fresh or new data after the first run
$sql = "SELECT name, amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data

$name = $resultarr['name'];
$amount = $resultarr['amount'];
$transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
$date = $resultarr['time_paid'];

//message template
$message = "Dear $name we have received $amount from you. MPESA transaction Id $transaction_id on $date.";

$mobilenumber = $resultarr['msisdn']; // get mobile number from array
$message_sent = $message;

$serviceArguments = array(
    "mobilenumber" => $mobilenumber,
    "message" => $message_sent
);

$client = new SoapClient("http://32.138.160.130:8080
```

Comment: You should add a column to the customers to see if the message is send, when this is not the case you send the message and change the column to send.

Comment: either flag new records and filter by that (e.g. `where new=1`, then set them to `0` when done), or keep track of the last ID you fetched, and then grab everything past that (`where id >= $last_processed_id`)

Comment: I have such a deja vu feeling about this question, as if I had seen the same one couple of hours ago...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because somebody with a very similar username asked the exact same question a couple of hours earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809225/preventing-selecting-the-same-data-over-and-over-again-from-a-php-mysql-database